# how do i open image file on a windows 7 machine programmatically via a url string using Windows Photo Viewer from a winform application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

as the topic suggest, how do i open image file (jpg, png & etc) on a windows 7 machine programmatically via a web link using Windows Photo Viewer from a winform application that im developing.

Comment: define your use scenario, do you mean a web-browser context menu (**_Open in Windows Photo Viewer**) that available on a hyperlink?

Comment: sorry that i left out the user scenario. user is suppose to be able to open a url string that contains the images from a winform application

Comment: you are trying to solve the problem that the image is opened by the default photo viewer, not Windows Photo Viewer (as you desired), right?

Comment: not really. i will welcome that actually. in actual fact, what i'm trying to achieve here is, based on an extension (.jpg, .doc, .png), i will search the registry to find the string of the default application associated with these extension. i'm able to open .xlsx, .doc file using System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProgramName, file url) but now i'm encountering problem opening .png, .jpg file because the associated program string returned is rundll32.exe or dllhost.exe which does nothing when i use Process.Start

Comment: you can call `Process.Start(fullpath.jpg)` to start the default photo viewer, if that is what you want. don't even have to query registry for associated application for the extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Referenced](http://www.sevenforums.com/software/180378-where-windows-photo-viewer-default-location.html) from sevenforums.

> Windows Photo Viewer is run by dllhost.exe COM Surrogate. Basically, it does not have it's own exe file, only dll.
>
> To start Windows Photo Viewer from command line you would have to use
> Code:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\rundll32.exe "%ProgramFiles%\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll", ImageView_Fullscreen %1
```

> where %1 is a full path to a file.

And you can launch Windows Photo viewer using `Process.Start`.

**Note: The file path must NOT contain double quote(")!**

```
string arg = "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Photo Viewer\\PhotoViewer.dll\", ImageView_Fullscreen  C:\\Users\\my\\SkyDrive\\Pictures\\Camera Roll\\1.jpg";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Windows\\System32\\rundll32.exe", arg);
```

Comment: i tried your method and i can't seem to get it to work.
Process.Start("%SystemRoot%\\System32\\rundll32.exe", "\"%ProgramFiles%\\Windows Photo Viewer\\PhotoViewer.dll\", ImageView_Fullscreen C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Pictures\\man_grey.jpg");

Comment: See my update, I have tested it.

Comment: yea thanks! however it doesn't seem to work if a URL is provided. is that normal? It launches Windows Photo Viewer but an error message that read 'Windows Photo Viewer can't open this picture because the file appears to be damaged, corrupted or is too large' is displayed instead of the picture.

Comment: Download the file to local drive first I am not sure if windows photo viewer is capable of download the file automatically

Comment: it's not capable of downloading the file automatically. thanks a lot though!